# Unlimited recursive while displaying time for every directory

Tags: linux, macos, unix, freebsd

I want to display all directories in my current directory recursively, but I also want to display the full date and time (even after 6 months). Considering I am using a Mac I had to use the FreeBSD format for this, which amounts to:

```
ls -aldFT ./*/*/*/*
```

I want to do unlimited recursive though, but I seem to be unable to use -R in combination with the FT parameter? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zsh` globstar feature-

```
ls -aldFT **/*
```

in `ksh` you have to turn on the feature

```
set -G
ls -aldFT **/*
```

if you have installed bash 4 then

```
shopt -s globstar
ls -aldFT **/*
```

or you could do use `find` with `stat`

```
find . -exec  stat -f '%Sp %4l   %10Su   %8Sg %12z  %22Sm   %N' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

That certainly helped a lot, thanks! What I needed in the end was:

```
find . -type d -exec  stat -f '%22Sm   %N' {} +
```

What does the 22Sm mean though? I dont notice much difference if I change that number in there.

Ps. I went for that solution mainly because:

```
ls -aldFT **/*
```

just resulted in Argument list too long, which is really annoying after updating bash to 4.0 to use this at all :)

Comment: The 22 is padding for the column, the S displays the m (modification time) as a string.